# Delete the Range of Columns in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to delete the range of columns but getting error "Application Defined or object defined error". In the below code wks is the worksheet and colStart and colEnd are variables with values.

```
Dim colDelete As String

colDelete = wks.Range(wks.Cells(1, colStart), wks.Cells(1, colEnd)).EntireColumn.Delete
```

Comment: This code works for me. Are you sure `wks` is a properly assigned worksheet object, and `colStart` and `colEnd` are >0 whole numbers? Are you sure the worksheet is not protected? Can you post some more of your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare your variables. **Always.**

```
dim colStart as long
dim colEnd as long
dim wks as Worksheet
```

It should work this way.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Yes vacip the colStart and colEnd has integer values as you can see in watch screen of my image. And also wks is properly assigned worksheet object.

Comment: Well, they are actually strings, not numbers. I'll post an answer, but you need to declare your variables.

Comment: Actually I have declared my variables in my code. The code is too long so not able to paste the whole code here.

Comment: Ok, so why does it say Type: "string" in your watches window?

Comment: Thanks Vacip. I got my mistake. My variables are string. My bad. Thanks a lot